# simple database (BAD_EXEC)

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, label

I am doing a simple project to prove my skills with iOS programming. I am trying to do a program in which you would enter a string, click submit and it would create a new label below with the text you entered. The more strings you would submit, the more labels would you have under each other. After I submit it the first time, nothing happens. If I submit a string second time, I get a BAD_EXEC error. Can you please help me out?

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize infoLabel;
@synthesize field;
@synthesize saveButton;

NSString *labelString = @""; // this string will hold all of my strings together
NSString *separator = @"|<->|"; // this is the separator that will separate strings in labelString

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [infoLabel release];
    [field release];
    [saveButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender // when submit button is clicked
{
    if(!([field.text isEqualToString:@""])) // check if anything was entered as the string
    {
        if([labelString isEqualToString:@""]) labelString = field.text; // if nothing is in stored in strings, write the current input
        else // if there already are some strings in there
        {
            NSString *temp = @"";
            temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", labelString, separator, field.text]; // prepare a new labelString to hold all my old strings + new one
            labelString = temp; // replace prepared string with old one
        }

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; // saving to database
        [defaults setObject:labelString forKey:@"saveString"];

        NSArray *labelText = [labelString componentsSeparatedByString:separator]; // create array of separated strings
        UILabel *label[[labelText count]]; // create array of labels
        for(int i = 0; i < [labelText count]; i++) // cycle through all labels
        {
            label[i] = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, i * 20 + 20, 320, 20)]; // create a label for each string that will be on a certain position (descending)
            label[i].text = labelText[i]; // set text for labol
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Where does it crash?  Post the stack trace, at the least.   Note also that `NSUserDefaults` is not a database and really shouldn't be used for storing more than configuration state for the app; where it was last opened, user options, that sort of thing.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/Introduction.html

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/AaMUBjD.png

Comment: @user2874028: referring to the snapshot you provided, could you click on the line that say `saveButton` (the one below the selected `objc_msgSend`) and post a new snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

> After I submit it the first time, nothing happens.

You create your UILabel, but you do not add them to your controller view:

```
    UILabel *label[[labelText count]]; // create array of labels
    for(int i = 0; i < [labelText count]; i++) // cycle through all labels
    {
        label[i] = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, i * 20 + 20, 320, 20)]; // create a label for each string that will be on a certain position (descending)
        label[i].text = labelText[i]; // set text for labol
        [self.view addSubview:label[i]];
    }
```

On the other hand, I do not understand why you use an array to store the labels. It does not seem to be necessary.

As to the crash, it is likely that it depends on accessing some object that has been deallocated. That is: in the first run, you allocate some object and store its reference weakly; the object is deallocated when the method ends; when you reenter the method, you try to access that object => crash.

That assignment `labelString = temp;` seems highly suspect to me... try to replace the static global variable `labelString` with a `strong` property in your controller (`@interface`):

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString* labelString;
```

EDIT:

I am not sure if declaring `labelString` as a property will fix the crash on the second tap. That's just a shot in the dark.

You should provide more info about the crash for me to be able to help more. You could:

1. set an exception breakpoint (google for it) so that after the crash Xcode will tell you on which line the crash happened and for what reason;
2. alternatively, simply set a breakpoint in `saveButton` and go step by step until the crash happens; then you will know exactly which statement you were trying to execute;
3. try and enable zombie detection in your Xcode scheme (google of it), so in case the issue is trying to access an already deallocated object, you will get the full report.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I tried the [self.view...] but it gave me this error: Instance method '-addSubView:' not found. (return type defaults to 'id') Also, im not sure where you want me to put the strong property. I have only few properties and those are my button, label and textfield. They are written in the .h file. I declared my string in the .m file.

Comment: From your comment, you said the error was '-addSubView:' not found.'  If you copied the error directly, than thats your issue, the method is `addSubview:UIView` not `addSubView:UIView` @user2874028

Comment: @user2874028: `addSubview` is spelled with a lowercase `v`... as to the property, you can declare it in your .h file, if you want, just like the others. See also my edit...